# AngularJS (1.5) refresh directive on state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I don't think it's reasonable to provide a code itself for this question, as there is too much of related code.

**The question** itself is - is it possible to re-initialize directive from the directive's controller (at the same time keeping the data originally passed into the directive). 
at the `$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess'` event?

**Circumstances:**

I have some directive (with multiple nested directives) controlling Google Maps InfoWindow. The page is split into 2 parts (Airbnb-style). 
Info window is open on the right side of the page on a google map. There are some action calls from infoWindow changing the state of `ui-router`. `$state` change reloading the `ui-view` on the left side on the page, but keeps the `ui-view` on the right side with the open Google Map and Info window unchanged.

**The problem:**

Once the $state changed from the call made from directive controlling the google map InfoWindow, everything goes right (ui-view on the left side is changed, map and IW remains the same). However, some of the functions withing the IW nested directives(uib-pagination and a few custom directives) stop working (at the same time, some keep working). 
I think that the solution will be to re-initialize the main IW directive.